# How do I increment pointer in stringtable?

Tags: c, string, ansi-c, string-table

I'm filling a stringtable char* data [500] with pointers to different strings.

```
char* data [500];
int  stringC = 0;
char PrintBuffer[200];

void data_display(void);
void printStringTable(void);

int main() {

    data_display(); //fill buffer
    printStringTable();
    return 0;
}
```

Here i use another Buffer so that i can store an Index in the String:

```
void data_display(void)
{
    int index =0;
    sprintf(PrintBuffer,"A Text %d\n", index);
    output(PrintBuffer);
    index ++;
    sprintf(PrintBuffer,"B Text %d\n",index);
    output(PrintBuffer);
    index ++;
    sprintf(PrintBuffer,"C Text %d\n",index);
    output(PrintBuffer);
}
```

When debugging I can see that the pointer always points to the same adress.

```
void output(char* Buffer)
{
    data[stringC]= Buffer;
    char*(*ptr)[500] = &data;
    stringC++;
    ptr+=stringC;
}

void printStringTable()
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        printf(data[i]);
    }
}
```

If I have pure strings without using another Buffer (PrintBuffer) every pointer points to a different adress and I get:

A Text 0
B Text 1
C Text 2

But in this constellation I get:

C Text 2
C Text 2
C Text 2

Is there a way to increment the pointer so that it points to a different adress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All pointers in the `data` array point to the same location, that is `PrintBuffer`.

You must allocate a new buffer for each of your strings.

The output function shoukd be modified like this:

```
void output(char* Buffer)
{
    char *newbuffer = strdup(Buffer) ;
    data[stringC]= newBuffer;
  // removed: this it's pointless       char*(*ptr)[500] = &data;
    stringC++;
  // removed: this it's pointless       ptr+=stringC;
}
```

Comment: Suggest a note about `free()`.